# How to implement sitecore site search

Tags: sitecore

I need to implement content site search based on sitecore API. 
I know how to set up crawler for Lucene.Net, but this would be some kind of search by predefined template, I need to implement search by result content (final html), it should works like close to google search. Is is possible to do in sitecore ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can look here if you are using Sitecore 7.http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Making-Google-Part-1.aspx Are 4 parts to make Sitecore search looking like Google

Comment: If you are looking to integrate it for Sitecore 6.x, then you should use the Advanced Database Crawler. Alex Shyba has a great video on it. http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the search to be based on the rendered HTML (are you really sure about that), some custom  magic is required.
Crawling the content is needed in such case, thus if the publised item is visitable (has an URL), you can use the HTMLAgility framework to get the HTML, strip the tags and add the content to the index in any (new) field you like...